# Coverting cURL to java for parse.com?

Tags: java, php, curl, parse-platform

I'm really struggling... The parse docs give this example on how to send a push, using curl:

```
curl -X POST \
 -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: myAppId" \
 -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: myAppKey" \
 -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
 -d '{
    "channels": [
      "Giants",
      "Mets"
    ],
    "data": {
      "alert": "The Giants won against the Mets 2-3."
    }
  }' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/push
```

how would I do this in plain java, for a desktop java program?

Comment: Sorry ... this is not a program writing service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not writing your code for you, or doing your research for you.

But the way to solve a problem like this is to break it down into subproblems.  For example:

- How to send an HTTP request in Java
- How to send a POST request in Java
- How to pass something in the request body.
- How to set the content type
- How to pass non-standard request headers
- How to construct JSON
- How to deal with the response.